# Does somebody have an idea why codeblocks stopped working and is just flickering when I try to open it?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I installed Codeblocks a while ago and also used it on a regular basis.
When I tried to start Codeblocks yesterday the window just flickered in and out of existence on the left side of my screen and the toolbar icon also flickered while starting and was then visible normally.
When I try to bring the Codeblocks window to the front by clicking the toolbar icon the flickering window appears again shortly but then dissapears.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be?
I searched the forum and could not find any similar issues.

Comment: Another detail that might be of interest: Every time I close codeblocks the notificiation "Layout changed - The perspective 'Code::Blocks default' has changed. Do you want to save it? Yes/No" appears. No matter what I choose, the problem remains and the notification reappears the next time i try to close the program.

Comment: You probably want to ask here: [http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=1.0](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?board=1.0)